# _jsonparsefailure Error With Kibana

Tags: json, logstash, kibana

I have setup Docker with Logstash, Elasticsearch and Kibana and sending data from my Extjs application over tcp. I know that my json is correct but still it gives **tag:_jsonparsefailure** error.

[My Logstash.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKNO4.png)

[Error on Kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGe2O.png)

How should I fix this?

Comment: According to Kibana, the message field is not json. Also you have json codec on one of your inputs, in addition to the filter. So it's not surprising it does not work

Comment: remove extjs tag, the error isn't in extjs

Comment: Removing json codec will not do the trick either because I tried it that way, too. So do you have any further suggestions? @baudsp

Comment: Could you indicate what does your logs look like when you receive them? (for example with stdout and the codec plain)